# create JSON array from C# collection using System.Web.Script.Serialization

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have this code

```
            var httpWebRequestAuthentication = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api");
        httpWebRequestAuthentication.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequestAuthentication.Accept = "en";
        httpWebRequestAuthentication.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en");
        httpWebRequestAuthentication.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequestAuthentication.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                agent_name = "my name",
                agent_password = "myPassword",
                countryCode = "US",
                requestType = "post",
                sales_representatives = new[] { // How do I create here a Foreach loop that will iterate a C# collection and create the JSON array?
                new {
                  product = "agent1",
                  primary_sales_representative= 1234,
                  secondary_sales_representative= 2345
                },
                new {
                  product = "agent2",
                  primary_sales_representative = 1111,
                  secondary_sales_representative= 2222
                }
                }
            });

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponseAuthentication = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequestAuthentication.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReaderAuthentication = new StreamReader(httpResponseAuthentication.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var resultAuthentication = streamReaderAuthentication.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

I want to change this code so my `sales_represetatives` JSON collection will be created from my c# list of sales representatives.

I couldn't find a way to insert a `foreach` loop in this code to create the JSON array?

Comment: I would say this is a crude way of doing serialization. If you create a class with the desired output, you can simply use Newtonsoft Json to serialize the object. Do you need any samples to do it this way?

Comment: Thank you @KrishnaChaithanyaMuthyala. the c# class I have is not identical to the JSON i need to POST. I also use this C# class to POST to other apis (different ones). is this information change your suggestion to use Newtonsoft?

Comment: Either way, I think using Newtonsoft library is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace that code:

```
 sales_representatives = new[] { // How do I create here a Foreach loop that will iterate a C# collection and create the JSON array?
            new {
              product = "agent1",
              primary_sales_representative= 1234,
              secondary_sales_representative= 2345
            },
            new {
              product = "agent2",
              primary_sales_representative = 1111,
              secondary_sales_representative= 2222
            }
            }
```

With the following one:

```
sales_representatives = yourCollection.Select(repr=>new {
  product = repr.ProductField,
  primary_sales_representative = repr.PrimaryField,
  secondary_sales_representative = repr.SecondaryField
}
```

This assumes that your c# list of sales representatives is stored in a collection named "yourCollection", and that each object in that collection has ProductField, PrimaryField and SecondaryField properties. Change to your liking.

Comment: Thank you @Arnaud.